# Firestore - Saving Money on Document Reads

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of 5,000 Artists from Firestore that I would like to load into my application as a searchable dropdown. The cost of doing this per user every page load is pricey. I have 10,000 active users a month.

I tried Algolia, but the number of users on the site makes it a very pricey option. And loading 5,000 records every page load adds up quickly with Firestore. My thought is to store the names and IDs of all of the artists in a single document array in Firestore so that the cost is only 1 per page load as opposed to 5,000. Then, load additional data when an Artist is selected.

```
artists = {
  uniqueId: 'Artist Name',
  uniqueId2: 'Second Artist Name',
}
```

I expect to save hundreds of thousands of document reads a day with this method. The only added annoyance is doing things client-side. But, this isn't too much trouble. I was hoping to gain insight into what others were doing. Should I consider storing some data in MySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want something easier to work with then instead of an array you could use key-value pairs for all artists in a single doc. Limits are 1MB per doc so even with 5,000 artists you should be well within the limits.

```
db.collection('artists').doc(_all).set({
  uniqueId: 'Artist Name',
  uniqueId2: 'Second Artist Name',
})
```

Then once you retrive the doc you can use `Object.values()` or `Object.entries()` to extract names and/or keys

If you want an even more flexible solution you could use cloud functions to keep an up-to-date version of a specific query or collection of documents either in firebase realtime db or another db like redis. Here's an article explaining how to do the latter

https://thecloudfunction.com/blog/firebase-cloud-functions-and-redis/

Comment: It never even crossed my mind to use Firebase alongside Firestore! That might be the easiest and quickest solution. Thanks for the tip on Redis as well.

Comment: Most welcome. Yes the billing model on realtime fits that sort of purpose much better I find, you can also add a cloud function to automatically sync data across on write from firestore to rtdb, or just add your own cron/triggerable methods

Comment: I personally do not recommend the current code, since now you will have artists collection with a document of 5000 fields all of which are indexed. Well even if you exempt the fields from indexing there is a limit of  200 only fields. Instead  I will advise to use a document with a single field and that field  is a map of key value pairs, Then you exempt indexing to this particular field.